# I have problem in 'yajra/laravel-oci8 v6.0.0'

Tags: php, laravel, xampp, composer-php, oracle-cloud-infrastructure

I cannot give the `composer install` command in VSCode. When I try this message appears.

```
"PHP Warning:  PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library 'oci8_12c' (tried: C:\xampp\php\ext\oci8_12c (N├úo foi poss├¡vel encontrar o m├│dulo especificado.), C:\xampp\php\ext\php_oci8_12c.dll (N├úo foi poss├¡vel encontrar o m├│dulo especificado.)) in Unknown on line 0

Warning: PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library 'oci8_12c' (tried: C:\xampp\php\ext\oci8_12c (N├úo foi poss├¡vel encontrar o m├│dulo especificado.), C:\xampp\php\ext\php_oci8_12c.dll (N├úo foi poss├¡vel encontrar o m├│dulo especificado.)) in Unknown on line 0
Loading composer repositories with package information
Installing dependencies (including require-dev) from lock file
Your requirements could not be resolved to an installable set of packages.

  Problem 1
    - Installation request for yajra/laravel-oci8 v6.0.0 -> satisfiable by yajra/laravel-oci8[v6.0.0].
    - yajra/laravel-oci8 v6.0.0 requires ext-oci8 >=2.0.0 -> the requested PHP extension oci8 is missing from your system.

  To enable extensions, verify that they are enabled in your .ini files:
    - C:\xampp\php\php.ini
  You can also run `php --ini` inside terminal to see which files are used by PHP in CLI mode.".
```

I am using XAMPP version 7.4.29, COMPOSER 1.10.5 and ORACLE INSTANT CLIENT 12.2

I tried to download the oci8_12c file and put it in the php folder, even so it's giving the same error.
I need help

Comment: did you put it in the `php/ext` folder?

Comment: You need to install the extension "oci8".

Comment: Did you check `phpinfo()` to see whether the extension was enabled properly?

Comment: did you put it in the php/ext folder? – IGP, R:
yes, I put the file in the folder and still the error continues.

Comment: Please add all clarification to your question by editing it